# Replace if-elses by a config file

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, nested-if

Consider a Java function as follows -

```
public MutablePair<List<String>,Boolean> getItemPair(Map<String,Object> myMap){
    MutablePair<List<String>,Boolean> SampleList(Map<String,Object> objectMap){
    MutablePair<List<String>,Boolean> finalMutablePair = new MutablePair<>;
    List<String> FinalList = new ArrayList<>();
    Boolean b = true;
    if(objectMap.get("a").toString().contains("Animal")){
        FinalList.add("Is an Animal");
        if(objectMap.get("w").toString().contains("Wild")){
             FinalList.add("Is a wild Animal");
             if(objectMap.get("b").toString().contains("Beautiful")){
                FinalList.add("Is a beautiful Animal");
             }
             else{
                FinalList.add("Is not beautiful Animal");
                b = false;
             }
            }
        else{
             FinalList.add("Is not a wild Animal");
             b= false;
            }
        }
    else{
        FinalList.add("Is not an Animal");
        b = false;
      }
        finalMutablePair.first = FinalList;
        finalMutablePair.second = b;
        return finalMutablePair;
    }
}
```

There are nested if elses up to 3 levels in this case. But in actual use cases it can be well more than 3. I am aiming to define the conditions in a config file , to remove these nested if elses. I am thinking of defining a json file or jsonpath or something on these lines, so that a Map can be given as the input and List of Strings and a Boolean can be returned as the output. Also the config file can be used at many other places, therefore removing redundant code.
Can someone suggest me with an answer, or a code link , how can this be achieved? Looking for defining conditions in a Config file

Comment: you want to put the 'conditions in a config file'??? what do you mean by that? even if you put the values in a config file, you would still need the if-else statements

Comment: No I want the config file to parse the map

Comment: You may want to search decision tables in camunda framework.

Comment: will that be used as a config file?

Comment: @DawsonSmith what exactly do you mean by a config file? config files don't "parse" anything. They can trigger code that does, but on itself, it's just that.